# How can solve these system of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $U(\rho,z)$ and $V(\rho,z)$ functions are given. 
We have the system of equations for these functions in the form
$$
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial\rho^2}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial U}{\partial\rho}+\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial z^2} = 0 \ ,
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial\rho} = \rho\left[\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial\rho}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}\right)^2 \right]\ ,
\qquad \frac{\partial V}{\partial z} = 2\rho\frac{\partial U}{\partial\rho}\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}\ ,
$$
Can we use separation of the variable in the first equation? 
How about in the second and the third equations?

Comment: Why would you need separation of variables for the second equation? Once you get the expression for $U$ the only thing you have to do is to find the constants for which the equations in $V$ would work.

Comment: As you see the first equation is simple and its can be written in terms of product of the two different function with respect to variables. But second and third equations are non linear equations that means we can not use superposition method for the function V that is problem?

Comment: For $V$ you do not care about superposition because it is fully defined by $U$ (it has no $V$ terms in its differential). So that means you get the general (!!!) solution for $U$ and then you plug it into the $V$ expression. The only thing is that you must correlate the "eigenfunction" contributions in $U$ such that you get a valid $V$ from the two expressions.

Comment: As far as I know in non linear equation we can not use superposition principle???

Answer (score 1):

I will start the solution problem over here to show you exactly what I mean. The super-position principle, as you mentioned exists in linear systems. Hence, for the first part:

$ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \rho^2}+\frac{ 1}{ \rho}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \rho}+\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial z^2} = 0 $

with $U = R(\rho)Z(z)$

we get:

$ R''+(1/\rho) R' = -\lambda^2 R$

$ R = a_1 Y_0(\lambda \rho) + a_2 J_0(\lambda \rho) $

Here, $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively.

$ Z'' = -\lambda^2 Z$

$ Z = b_1 \sin(\lambda z)+b_2 \cos(\lambda z)$

Next, as I tried to mention, $V$ depends only on $U$. There is no need of anything like the superposition principle:

$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial z} = 2\rho R'Z'(RZ)$

$ V = 2\rho R'R\big(\int Z'Z\partial z\big) +f(\rho) = \rho R'RZ^2 +f(\rho)$

$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial \rho} = \rho R''RZ^2 + R'RZ^2 + \rho (R')^2 Z^2 +f'(\rho)$

We also have: 
$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial \rho} = \rho ((R')^2Z^2+R^2(Z')^2)$

Then you can use the quantities $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,\lambda$ and $f(\rho)$ to make sense of the equality:

$\rho R''RZ^2 + R'RZ^2 + \rho (R')^2 Z^2 +f'(\rho) = \rho ((R')^2Z^2+R^2(Z')^2)$

$\rho (-R'/\rho -\lambda^2 R)RZ^2 + R'RZ^2 + \rho (R')^2 Z^2 +f'(\rho) = \rho ((R')^2Z^2+R^2(Z')^2)$

$ f'(\rho) = \rho R^2(\lambda^2 Z^2+(Z')^2)$

Probably you should check again, but I believe that $ (\lambda^2 Z^2+(Z')^2) $ is always constant (i.e. it does not depend on $z$). Therefore, you will get:

$ f'(\rho) = \rho R^2(\text{some constant in }b_1,b_2,\lambda)$

and you can solve for $V$

Comment: Please see below

Answer (score -1):

Snifkes, Thank you very much for your solution. Actually, I have solved this problem in the prolate coordinates, 
$$
\rho=\sqrt{(x^2-1)(1-y^2)} \ , z=xy
$$ 
and we get
$$
\left[\left(x^2-1\right)U_x\right]_x +
\left[\left(1-y^2\right)U_y\right]_y=0 \ ,
$$
$$
V_x = \frac{1-y^2}{x^2-y^2}\left[x(x^2-1)U_x^2-x(1-y^2)U_y^2
-2y(x^2-1)U_xU_y\right] \ ,
$$
$$
V_y = \frac{x^2-1}{x^2-y^2}\left[y(x^2-1)U_x^2-y(1-y^2)U_y^2
+2x(1-y^2)U_xU_y\right] \ ,
$$

Solution of the first equation is
$$
U(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n P_n(x)+b_n Q_n(x))(c_n P_n(x)+d_n Q_n(x))
$$
But my question was different: You are making separation of variable in the function $U(\rho,z)$, finally it depend on $\lambda$ which is separation constant and you need to sum over lambda like: $U= \sum_{\lambda} R_{\lambda}(\rho)Z_{\lambda}(z)$ - which is correct, but other two equations are not linear. As far as I know it is impossible to use summation over with separation constant for non linear equations. What do you think about it?

Comment: I think the problem is in your perception of what is the superposition principle (SP). The superposition principle is used for linear PDEs to get a solution. However, the equations in $V$ are not partial differential equation problems per-se. Meaning, both equations simply suggest $V_x = f(U)$ and $V_y = g(U)$ which do not have anything to do with the SP since $U$ must be defined. If the function describing $U$ was nonlinear, than what you assume is right.

Comment: I meant if the PDE describing $U$ was nonlinear in the last sentence.